# Get everything before a certain symbol in a array of symbols

Tags: arrays, ruby

Let's say I would have a array of symbols, like:

```
[:ONE,:TWO,:THREE,:FOUR,:FIVE,:SIX,:SEVEN,:EIGHT]
```

How can I get, for example, everything before `:FIVE`?

The expected result of the example would be `[:ONE,:TWO,:THREE,:FOUR]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
syms = [:ONE,:TWO,:THREE,:FOUR,:FIVE,:SIX,:SEVEN,:EIGHT]
syms.slice_before(:FIVE).first #=> [:ONE, :TWO, :THREE, :FOUR]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
syms = [:ONE,:TWO,:THREE,:FOUR,:FIVE,:SIX,:SEVEN,:EIGHT]
syms[0..(syms.index(:FIVE) - 1)]
```

Comment: You could use three dots: `syms[0...syms.index(:FIVE)]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [:ONE,:TWO,:THREE,:FOUR,:FIVE,:SIX,:SEVEN]
```

**#1 Use [Array#first](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-first) with an argument and [Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index)**

```
arr.first(a.index(:FIVE))
  #=> [:ONE, :TWO, :THREE, :FOUR]
```

**#2 Use Ruby's [flip-flop operator](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop)**

```
arr.select { |sym| true unless sym==:FIVE..false }
  #=> [:ONE, :TWO, :THREE, :FOUR]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [:ONE,:TWO,:THREE,:FOUR,:FIVE,:SIX,:SEVEN,:EIGHT]
a.map.with_index{|x,i| i < a.index(:FIVE) ? x : nil}.compact
# => [:ONE, :TWO, :THREE, :FOUR]
```